# php code for receiving data from pdf forms

Tags: php

In my project,i'm using pdf forms for application form from clients.........
How i can receive data from pdf after clicking submit ....Can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Just take a look at section 2 of this intro (http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/tutorial.php):

> Using a PDF form to allow users to fill in the data.
>   When using multi-page or long forms (a job application form for example), you may want to allow your visitors to simply fill in the PDF file to preserve formatting. You have 3 options:
>
> Have the users print the PDF and fill it in by hand and mail it,
>
> Have the users type in the information using the PDF, print it and mail it or
>
> Have the users type in the information using the PDF and submit it online.
>
> Because of the nature of PDF documents, you can be fairly certain that any of these options will produce similar results. We can cover all three options without additional effort (assuming you want to be able to accept the submission online in the first place).
>
> Create the PDF that your visitors will fill out. In most cases, this will be the exact PDF that you created earlier with an added submit button, so let's add that.
>
> Open your PDF document that has the form and select the button tool.
>
> Draw the button in the document. This is what the users will click to submit the form.
>
> Select the Actions tab of the field properties.
>
> Select the Submit a Form option under the Select Action field and click the Add button.
>
> Select the HTML Export Format.
>
> Enter the URL of the processing script.
>
> Select All fields option for the Field Selection
>
> Select All fields option for the Field Selection
>
> Click OK

Your PHP file can then access your submitted by your PDF via

```
$_POST['your field name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope thus URL will give you better way...

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php
```